# A proper closing expression for informal email

Tags: expressions, email, internet, technology

What is an expression that you can use at the end of an informal email, when you forgot something and want to add it to the email after your signature?

Comment: In English, the traditional is to use the abbreviation ps (alternatively P.S., or PS,) the abbreviation for the Latin _post scriptum_. I no longer use it in emails, since it's so easy to go back and edit the email to inclue what I forgot originally forgot. I do, however, still use it in handwritten correspondence on occasion.

Comment: @brasshat, yes, the expression to use is "up-arrow, up-arrow, up-arrow, ..." and then start typing your message :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use either P.S. or N.B. For informal articles, P.S. is the apt choice.

P.S. being post scriptum, and N.B. (*nota bene*) if it is something important you want to draw the reader's attention to.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_script

P.S. : In case of an email, the text can be altered, even if you forget to write something.
And if you have already sent it, then you will have to send a mail again, including the matter you wanted to write.

Comment: When you have forgot something and want to add it, after you have signed the e-mail but before you have sent it, you can just alter the body of the e-mail so as to include it, without your reader's even being aware that it is an afterthought. In the context of e-mail as opposed to pen-and-ink letter-writing, the function of "P.S." has everything to do with whether you want something to *seem* an afterthought, and nothing whatever to do with whether it actually *is* one.

Comment: Ah yes! Honestly,I wrote it in the case of letters. Editing , for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

By the way I forgot to add that...
Forgot to mention that...

.... is perfect for informal emails.